# Parse: How to add object to the user, who is not not the current user

Tags: android, parse-platform, associated-object

i have created my app, in which I have created several users. The challenge is, I need to construct the app in a way that, while I am logged in as a user (say User A), I can add input an object into another user (say User B). So, while am logged in as user A, I can input the data that will be saved into one of the empty field, of User B. Can you assist which way, I can arrange this? In short, how can I create an object to associate with the User B.

Here is the thing, while I am logged in as User A, I want to add "Scores" for both user A and B. for instance, if the user A's score is 7, and B's score is 20, I could add the scores while logged in the activity A, and they will be added in the field "Scores" of the corresponding users.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you mean by "add input an object into another user".   Also language and platform would help.

Comment: Here is the thing, while I am logged in as User A, I want to add "Scores" for both user A and B. for instance, if the user A's score is 7, and B's score is 20, I could add the scores while logged in the activity A, and they will be added in the field "Scores" of the corresponding users.

Comment: I am using Parse on Android by the way.....

Comment: Handle this in a different table. Create a one-to-many relationship. It will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

```
you should go for parse cloud code which is written in java script

refer this link to know more
https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code

then you just edit main.js
deploy and call that cloud code from your code

// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.define("updateTable", function(request, response) {
var currentUserId=request.params.currentLoggedinUser;
var userToBeUpdatedId=request.params.userToBeUpdated;

  var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
          user = new User({ objectId: userToBeUpdatedId });

   user.addUnique("followers",currentUserId);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });

});

deploy this code using  comand "parse deploy" from terminal.
call this code from your code like

ParseCloud.callFunction("updateTable", params);

i hope it will help.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that Parse is setup by default is so that only the current users data can be editted in the User table. You could probably change the settings for the table however, this could cause security issues.

What I would suggest would be to create a 'Scores' tables. There you could have a row for each user. with a 'userID' column which contained the objectId of the user to reference the user. You could then have a score column which you could update whenever you wanted.

Alternatively to storing the objectId of the user in the userID column you could make an association between the Scores row and the user. See the Parse documentation for how to create associations. https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-associations